# Calling NvAPI_GPU_SetEDID on Nvidia card

Tags: c#, nvidia, nvapi

How do you call this method on Nvidia GPU:

```
NVAPI_INTERFACE NvAPI_GPU_SetEDID (
    NvPhysicalGpuHandle hPhysicalGpu,
    NvU32   displayOutputId,
    NV_EDID *   pEDID 
)
```

Src: http://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/gameworkslibrary/coresdk/nvapi/group__gpu.html#ga6a41b31dd9743120213435d985f8fbcf

I need to execute the above command to remove all EDID set on all DisplayOutputs on our new Quadro Graphics Cards. Based on the API documentation, I tried searching for *NvPhysicalGpuHandle* and came across this project/library:

https://github.com/openhardwaremonitor/openhardwaremonitor/blob/master/Hardware/Nvidia/NVAPI.cs

This does not have the method I need `NvAPI_GPU_SetEDID`

I am not hardware programmer, I just need to be able to call this one command. any ideas? Can this be achieved using `nvapi.dll/nvapi64.dll` via `pinvoke` or something?

Answer (score 2):

I personally didn't test this, but you can try the library and see if it can set EDID information without any problem, if it fails, please open an issue.

https://github.com/falahati/NvAPIWrapper

---

Here is how you should do it,

1. First, you need to find the right `DisplayDevice` or `GPUOutput` that you want to write EDID information to. There are multiple ways to do so.

   - Get a list of all `PhysicalGPU`s in the system using the `NvAPIWrapper.GPU.PhysicalGPU.GetPhysicalGPUs()` static method, then select the `PhysicalGPU` you desire based on your logic. After finding the right `PhysicalGPU`, use the `NvAPIWrapper.GPU.PhysicalGPU.GetDisplayDevices()` method to get a list of all connected `DisplayDevice`s to that GPU and store the right one in a variable.
   - Instead of searching for connected `DisplayDevice`s, you can also go for the `GPUOutput`s. Just like before, you first need to find the right `PhysicalGPU` and then you can get a list of all `GPUOutput`s using the `NvAPIWrapper.GPU.PhysicalGPU.ActiveOutputs` property and store the right `GPUOutput` in a variable.
   - Another way to find the right `DisplayDevice` is to go for a list of all `Displays`. To do so, you need to use the `NvAPIWrapper.Display.Display.GetDisplays()` static method. This returns an array of `Display`s. Then using the `NvAPIWrapper.Display.Display.DisplayDevice` property, you can get the corresponding `DisplayDevice` of a `Display`.
2. After finding the right `DisplayDevice` or `GPUOutput`, you should use the `NvAPIWrapper.GPU.PhysicalGPU.WriteEDIDData()` method. This method allows you to write EDID data stored in a byte array to the `DisplayDevice` or the `GPUOutput` you selected before.

Note: Make sure to capture `NVIDIAApiException` and check for the `NVIDIAApiException.Status` property in case something went wrong.